# Number of subgroups of $S_4$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, permutations

> How to find the number of subgroups of $S_4$ and list them?

For order $1$ it is {${e}$}, order $2$, we will consider   $<(12)>$, $<(23)>$, $<(34)>$, $<(13)>$, $<(14)>$, $<(24)>$, for order $3$ we will consider $<(123)>$, $<(124)>$, $<(143)>$, $<(234)>$, for order 4 we will look at $<(1234)>$, $<(1324)>$, and so on. $A_4$ will also be there. I don't think these will be all ...

Comment: Why don't you do things in order? Of order two you have $\;\langle (12)\rangle\,,\,\langle (13)\rangle\,,\,\langle (14)\rangle\;$, etc.

Comment: The subgroups that you have listed so far are each generated by *one* element, i.e. cyclic.  Not all subgroups are cyclic.  Inside of $S_4$, you should find an isomorphic copy of the Klein four group $C_2 \times C_2$, for instance.

Comment: Also $<(1,2)(3,4)>$ is an example of a group of order $2$ that you did not list, and there groups of order $4$ that you did not list, such as $<(1,2),(3,4)>$.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative approach is to start from the top and work down. For example, you know that $[S_4 : A_4 ]=2$, so your "first" subgroup is $S_4$. The subsequent subgroups would be $A_4$ and its conjugates. Now you localize the problem and just need to list the subgroups of $A_4$ and its conjugates.

Now $\vert A_4\vert =12$, so check if it has subgroups of index $2$ ($A_4$ has no subgroups of index 2, but what about $3$?). Continue the process. Eventually you get to subgroups of order $2$ and $3$, which are of course simple. Drawing a lattice of subgroups might help you avoid missing any subgroups.

Answer (score 1):

Using an old version of GAP can help you sorting these subgroups:

```
gap> LoadPackage("sonata");;
    s4:=SymmetricGroup(4);;
    e:=Subgroups(s4);
    Size(e);
```

---

```
 Group(()), Group([ (1,3)(2,4) ]), Group([ (1,4)(2,3) ]), 
 Group([ (1,2)(3,4) ]), Group([ (3,4) ]), Group([ (2,4) ]), Group([ (2,3) ]),
 Group([ (1,4) ]), Group([ (1,3) ]), Group([ (1,2) ]), Group([ (2,4,3) ]), 
 Group([ (1,3,2) ]), Group([ (1,3,4) ]), Group([ (1,4,2) ]), 
 Group([ (1,4)(2,3), (1,3)(2,4) ]), Group([ (1,2)(3,4), (3,4) ]), 
 Group([ (1,3)(2,4), (2,4) ]), Group([ (1,4)(2,3), (2,3) ]), 
 Group([ (1,2)(3,4), (1,3,2,4) ]), Group([ (1,3)(2,4), (1,2,3,4) ]), 
 Group([ (1,4)(2,3), (1,2,4,3) ]), Group([ (3,4), (2,4,3) ]), 
 Group([ (1,3), (1,3,2) ]), Group([ (1,3), (1,3,4) ]), 
 Group([ (1,4), (1,4,2) ]), Group([ (1,3)(2,4), (1,4)(2,3), (1,2) ]), 
 Group([ (1,2)(3,4), (1,4)(2,3), (1,3) ]), 
 Group([ (1,2)(3,4), (1,3)(2,4), (1,4) ]), 
 Group([ (1,3)(2,4), (1,4)(2,3), (2,4,3) ]), 
 Group([ (1,3)(2,4), (1,4)(2,3), (2,4,3), (1,2) ]) 

30
```

In this updated but **not** a new version of [GAP 4.6.4](http://mail.gap-system.org/pipermail/forum/2013/004130.html), you may use the following codes without calling `sonata` instead:

```
gap>s4:=SmallGroup(24,12);;
    e:=AllSubgroups(s4);
    Size(e);
```