# Find all abelian subgroups of 4-element permutation group

Tags: abstract-algebra

I have to: "Find all abelian subgroups of a $4$-element permutation group $\Sigma_4$"

I don't know what is $\Sigma_4$. Don't know how to bite this topic. The exercise seems too general to me. Any help?

Comment: should I use the fact that cyclic implies abelian? But how can I find ALL of them?

Comment: Look here which subgroups are abelian: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/566997/number-of-subgroups-of-s-4. See also here: http://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Subgroup_structure_of_symmetric_group:S4

Comment: Ok, so all cyclic groups are abelian. So there are 24 abelian subgroups (there are 24 elements in this group, and a group generated by one element is cyclic). So how do I find all of them?

Comment: I'd advice you first to learn about the group $\;S_n\;$ (this is the most used notation for what you wrote $\;\Sigma_n\;$). This group also has abelian subgroups that are **not** cyclic.

Comment: I know $S_4$ is the group of permutations of set $\{1,2,3,4\}$

Comment: Well @luka5z, in fact $\;\Sigma_4=S_4\;$

Comment: There is a simple algorithm for gaining intuition for a problem that is too difficult, which is to make it simpler.  For example, can you solve the question for $S_3$?  If not, how about $S_2$?  $S_1$?  For example, by looking at $S_3$, you can see that there are $5$ abelian subgroups, not $6$, so your idea of counting elements must have a flaw somewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All subgroups of order $n\le 4$ of $S_4$ are abelian, and all subgroups of order $n\ge 5$ are non-abelian. The latter are $S_3, D_8,A_4$ and $S_4$, up to isomorphism. The abelian subgroups up to isomorphism then are the trivial group, the cyclic group of order $2$, $3$ and $4$, and the Klein four-group $V_4$. Here $V_4$ is abelian but not cyclic. If you have to find *all* abelian subgroups, then we must list all possible subgroups of order $n\le 4$.